# matlab-emacs doesn't open a file for edit (2014b)

Tags: emacs, matlab, emacsclient

I downloaded and installed the matlab-emacs project from http://matlab-emacs.sourceforge.net/ using the dl_emacs_support.m script and edited my .emacs file according to the instructions.

When I run

```
M-x matlab-shell
```

The matlab shell runs successfully, and the following line is shown:

```
>> addpath('/home/lab/yuvval/externals/matlab-emacs/toolbox','-begin'); rehash; emacsinit('emacsclient -n');
```

However when I try to edit a file, nothing happens. Even no error messages..

```
edit tmp.m
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? I would love to be able to edit and debug matlab code from emacs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding to emacsinit.m the following line:

```
setenv('EDITOR', clientcommand);
```

on the last line of the `if usejava(..`) block and starting the matlab mode on the .emacs file

```
;; Setting up matlab-mode
(server-start)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/your/matlab/emacs/path")
(load-library "matlab-load")
```